# Метод Рунге-Кутты для решения системы ДУ

Tags: c++, математика

Здравствуйте, решаю я систему ДУ первого порядка(это уравнение Лотки-Вальтерры). На самом деле, там вместо чисел должны быть переменные, но я их пока опустил.
[image: Условие]

Так вот, написал я такой

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    double t;
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    double  a = 0.0,    // начальное время
            b = 10.0;    // конечное время
    double  h = 0.02;   // шаг
    int   u0[] = {100, 50}; // количество людей/хищников в начале

    vector<Data> data;
    Data start;
    start.t = a;
    start.x = u0[0];
    start.y = u0[1];
    data.push_back(start);

    int stepCount = (b / h) + 1;
    double currentTime = a + h;

    double  x, y;
    double  x_prev = start.x,
            y_prev = start.y;
    double K[4];
    for (int j = 1; j <= stepCount; j++)
    {
        // Решаем X
        K[0] = (2.0-0.02*y_prev) * x_prev;
        K[1] = (2.0-0.02*(y_prev + h*K[0]/2.0))  * (x_prev + h*K[0]/2.0);
        K[2] = (2.0-0.02*(y_prev + h*K[1]/2.0))  * (x_prev + h*K[1]/2.0);
        K[3] = (2.0-0.02*(y_prev + h*K[2]))    * (x_prev + h*K[2]);
        x   = x_prev + (K[0] + 2.0*K[1] + 2.0*K[2] + K[3])/6.0;

        // Решаем Y
        K[0] = (-1.0*y_prev  + 0.01*x_prev*y_prev);
        K[1] = (-1.0*(y_prev + h*K[0]/2.0) + 0.01*(x_prev + h*K[0]/2.0)   * (y_prev + h*K[0]/2.0));
        K[2] = (-1.0*(y_prev + h*K[1]/2.0) + 0.01*(x_prev + h*K[1]/2.0)   * (y_prev + h*K[1]/2.0));
        K[3] = (-1.0*(y_prev + h*K[2]/2.0) + 0.01*(x_prev + h*K[2])     * (y_prev + h*K[2]));
        y   = y_prev + (K[0] + 2.0*K[1] + 2.0*K[2] + K[3])/6.0;

        Data currentValues;
        currentValues.x = x;
        currentValues.y = y;
        currentValues.t = currentTime;
        data.push_back(currentValues);

        x_prev = x;
        y_prev = y;

        currentTime += h;
    }

    for (Data dt : data)
    {
        cout << dt.t << "\t" <<  dt.x << "\t" << dt.y << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done! Steps: " << stepCount << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << sizeof(Data)*data.size() << " bytes" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но, увы, что-то на выходе у меня всё ужасно.
Все значения NaN. 
Скорее всего, я ошибся с уравнениями. Но я так и не могу найти где. Вроде всё правильно.

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Лень лезть в справочники за формулами, но навскидку - разве тут, скажем, ` x   = x_prev + (K[0] + 2.0*K[1] + 2.0*K[2] + K[3])/6.0;` сумму этих `K` не нужно множить на `h` или что-то вроде того?

Comment: @Harry и правда, оказывается, надо было умножить. Это опечатка у меня в справочнике значит. Спасибо большое. Кстати, я проверил решение с Matlab-овским ode45 (Тоже Рунге-Кутты метод). Значения немного отличаются. Под конец у меня разница на 15(и X и Y). Странно. Спасибо еще раз. Теперь всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал в своем комментарии Harry, Вы неверно ввели формулы.

```
x   = x_prev + (K[0] + 2.0*K[1] + 2.0*K[2] + K[3]) / 6.0 * h;
y   = y_prev + (K[0] + 2.0*K[1] + 2.0*K[2] + K[3]) / 6.0 * h;
```

И на будущее, я Вам советую при написании любых программ отлаживать их либо в любой IDE (они умеют показывать все переменные и их значения), либо, если Вы программируете в блокноте, то ставьте в программе строки отладочной печати, например:

```
cout << x << y <<  dt.x << t << K[1] << K[2] << K[3] << K[4] << endl;
```

В Вашей программе уже на 2 шаге цикла видно, что значения начали взлетать.

Comment: Я и так использую IDE(у меня Qt Creator). Мне и так было видно, что значения не такие, которые нужны. Проблема оказалась в опечатке в моём справочнике. Спасибо